# NUnit Check availability my ActionFilterAttribute on controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, actionfilterattribute

How can I check for the availability of my `ActionFilterAttribute` on controller/action in ASP.NET MVC3?

I'm using NUnit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
// arrange
Expression<Action<HomeController>> expression = (HomeController c) => c.Index();
var mc = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;

// act
var actual = mc.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyActionFilterAttribute), false);

// assert
Assert.IsTrue(actual.Any());
```

which verifies that `MyActionFilterAttribiute` has been used to decorate the Index action on Home controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    [MyActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And How can I check for the availability of my ActionFilterAttribute on CONTROLLER (not action) in ASP.NET MVC3?

Comment: The same way, using reflection.